# jQuery Datatables Export Buttons Dynamic file name and title

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

I use jQuery datatable and Export buttons.

I change the filename and the title.

My problem is that I want the title to be dynamic, based on the filters and custom filters.

My problem is that The file name configured on the first load only

```
           .withButtons([
                    {
                            extend: "excelHtml5",
                            filename :$scope.getFileName(false),
                            title:$scope.getFileName(true),
                            exportOptions: {
                                    columns: ':visible'
                            },
                            //CharSet: "utf8",
                            exportData: { decodeEntities: true}

                    },
```

Comment: Why was the question suddenly downvoted - any particular reason ..?

Comment: all my question downvoted :(.... maybe it's because english mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course `$scope.getFileName()` is only called once, or the number of times you intentionally call it. Go the other way around : Use the [**`init()`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.init) function along with a `$watch` :

```
.withButtons([{
  extend: "excelHtml5",
  //filename: $scope.getFileName(false),
  //title: $scope.getFileName(true),
  exportOptions: {
    columns: ':visible'
  },
  //CharSet: "utf8",
  exportData: {
    decodeEntities: true
  },

  init: function(dt, node, config) {
     $scope.watch('fileName', function()  
        //config.filename is in fact config.title + config.extension
        config.title = $scope.fileName.title;
        config.extension = $scope.fileName.extension;
     })
  }

}])
```

You are not explaining why you need to use a `$scope.getFileName()` despite you are using angular where such things is easily automated. With the above you can now update a `fileName` struct on `$scope` whenever it is needed, and the export filename will change accordingly

```
$scope.fileName = {
   extension: '.xls',
   title: 'my-table-export'
}
```

Comment: init: function(dt, node, config) {
                                            $scope.$watch(function(){ return $scope.fileName.title }, function(params){
                                                    config.title = $scope.fileName.title;

                                            });
                                    }

Comment: @24sharon - not nessecary with a return handler, consider the `$watch` as a "stupid" event handler inside your `init()`.

Comment: If I write "$scope.watch('fileName'," like your code, I got an error like $scope does not has watch function